# a command to get the lines around a specific line of a text file

Tags: text

I'm looking for a command to get text around a specific line of a file.

ex:
file content:

a

b

c

d

e

f

g

h

i

j

a command like:
]$ commandname -text f -lines 3
giving the output

c

d

e

f

g

h

i

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're running a *nix:

```
grep -C 3 f filename
```

If you want *x* lines before f and *y* lines after:

```
grep -A y -B x f filename
```

Comment: Awesome!! Didn't know grep could do that. Thank you very much!